# Request uri read permission if uri is already known

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm using Xamarin to develop an Android app.

I have an image picker which I use to select an image. Once retrieved, I save the image uri in local sqlite database. I have requested the correct permissions when I created the intent for persistable read permission.

The issue I'm having is when I do an update to my app, I lose the uri read permission. My app UID changes or the permission for that uri is revoke my app. I get the error no persistable permission Grants found for uid.

What I would like to know if it's possible to request the permission for the uri again without using an intent and having the user reselect the image?  Is there a way for me to stop my uid from changing so that on update the existing uri permissions still work.

*******Update*******

Below is the Image intent i use to retrieve the image:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
{
    if (AndroidFilePermission.GetPermission(this, OPEN_IMAGE_CODE))
    {
        imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionOpenDocument);            
        imageIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantPersistableUriPermission);
    }
}
```

Below is the OnActivityResult when the Intent Picker callback returns to my activity. I save this uri in SQLite DB.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            var takeFlags = imageIntent.Flags
                            & (ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission
                            | ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok && requestCode == OPEN_IMAGE_CODE)
            {
                image_path = data.Data;
                this.ContentResolver.TakePersistableUriPermission(image_path, 
                takeFlags);
                this.img_field.Text = 
                System.IO.Path.GetFileName(image_path.Path);
                LaunchDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                //create condition for when image/sound path cannot be resolved
                LaunchDialog();
            }
}
```

Comment: `I have requested the correct permissions when I created the intent for persistable read permission.`. Impossble. But then show your intent instead of just talking about it.

Comment: i added the code where uri permission is being requested with the Intent and persisted.

Comment: What language is this? Please add a language/ide tag.

Comment: `imageIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantPersistableUriPermission);` That makes no sense. You cannot grant permissions. You can only get them from a content provider in onActivityResult() and then make them persistable. Well that you are doing. Which Android version on your device? Try devices with different Android versions.

Comment: `The issue I'm having is when I do an update to my app, I lose the uri read permission. ` Very strange and hard to believe. Updating does not release permissions.

Comment: Are the permissions persistant after restart of app? After reboot of device?

Comment: @greenapps so I don't need to add the flags in the intent, good to know.

Comment: The permissions work fine after restart of the app and rebooting the device. I'm trying this on Nexus 6P, Samsung note 8 and emulator with Android 8 API 26. All lose access to the uri once I push an update.